# Can anyone identify this IC marked AFGMG?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, reverse-engineering

I am reverse engineering a PCB. It has an unknown IC marked AFGMG.

IC details:

- Name on IC = AFGMG
- 8 pin
- IC size = 1.6x3 mm

It looks like this phone cannot send a better picture.

PCB:

[image: pcb]

Schematic:

If pin number 1 is the pin below the "A" and the dot, then pin 2 is GND, pin 4 is VCC, and pin 5 is POWER of the board.

[image]

AFGMG is in the center:

[image: AFGMG is in center]

Comment: It would help to have a well focused picture that shows the markings, and details on what the board does.

Comment: It looks like this can not send a better picture

Comment: The poor photo may limit answers.  What about board function?

Comment: Might be a [Silergy](https://www.silergy.com) part. They have a few devices in TSOT23-8 packages and they usually use 5 character markings. I can't find a part with a `AFxyz` marking, but a lot of their datasheets are confidential, so it's still possible.

Comment: @nanash1 thank you very helpful